# Hopf invariant of composition of functions

Tags: differential-topology

Given two functions $f: S^{2p-1} \to S^p$ and $g: S^{p} \to S^{p}$, I want to prove that

\begin{equation}
H(f) = (\text{deg}(g))^2 H(f),
\end{equation}

where $H(f)$ is the Hopf invariant of $f$. I first tried to analyze the problem by assuming that $g$ preserves orientations. That is if $y \neq z$ are two distinct regular values of $g \circ f$ and since $(g \circ f)^{-1}(w) = \coprod_{u \in g^{-1}(w)} f^{-1}(u)$, then

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
H(g\circ f) & = l\left((g \circ f)^{-1}(y),(g \circ f)^{-1}(z)\right) 
\\ &= l\left(\coprod_{x \in g^{-1}(y)} f^{-1}(x), \coprod_{u \in g^{-1}(z)} f^{-1}(u)\right) \\ & = \sum_{x \in g^{-1}(y)} \sum_{u \in g^{-1}(z)} l\left( f^{-1}(x),f^{-1}(u)\right) \\ & = \sum_{x \in g^{-1}(y)} \sum_{u \in g^{-1}(z)} H(f) \\ & = H(f) \sum_{x \in g^{-1}(y)} \sum_{u \in g^{-1}(z)} 1 \\ & = H(f) \; (\text{deg}(g))^2.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

The sixth equality holds if $g$ preserves orientations. Here $l$ represents the linking number.

Is the above correct?

This was my idea to solve the problem in the case that g preserves orientations; however, in the general case I am stuck. This is problem 15 of Milnor's Topology from the Differentiable Point of View.

Comment: The preimage orientation will show up in line 2, won’t it?

Comment: Yes it should be.

Comment: So follow the signs through :)